# How to read XML using NSXMLParser, when I have more than once node of same name, in different category?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, nsxmlparser

How can I such type of Response of XML, using NSXMLParser, I am confused about two "clicks", it will hit, so how to manage flow and save data with one object, help me out,

```
</campaign_summary_response>

<summary> <clicks>6</clicks>
<conversions>1</conversions>      
<conversion_rate>0.1666666666666666666666666667</conversion_rate>     
<revenue>22.26555000000000</revenue> 
<revenue_converted>22.26555000000000</revenue_converted>     
<currency_symbol>$</currency_symbol>  
<currency_symbol_converted>$</currency_symbol_converted>
</summary>

<campaigns>
<campaign> <offer_id>100</offer_id>
<offer_name>$100 Wendy's Gift Card + Free Frosty</offer_name>     
<campaign_id>1781</campaign_id> <vertical_name>Free Stuff</vertical_name> 
<price_format>CPA</price_format>
<price>0.0000</price> 
<impressions>0</impressions>
<clicks>6</clicks>   
<conversions>1</conversions>
<conversion_rate>0.1666666666666666666</conversion_rate>  
<revenue>15.0000</revenue>
<revenue_converted>22.26555000000000</revenue_converted> 
<epc>2.50000000000000000000000</epc>
<currency_symbol>€</currency_symbol>   
<currency_symbol_converted>$</currency_symbol_converted>
</campaign> </campaigns>

</campaign_summary_response>
```

How do I code following delegate method

```
    - (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser 
               didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName
               namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI 
               qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName {
```

So that i can save all values in one object and show on display.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `didStartElement` method.

```
if([elementName isEqualToString:@"summary"]) summary = YES;
if([elementName isEqualToString:@"campaign"]) campaign = YES;
```

In `didEndElement` method.

```
if(summary) {

    if([elementName isEqualToString:@"revenue"]) // revenue in summary
    if([elementName isEqualToString:@"summary"]) summary = NO;
}

if(campaign) {

    if([elementName isEqualToString:@"revenue"]) // revenue in campaign
    if([elementName isEqualToString:@"campaign"]) campaign = NO;
}
```